# Grabing background color in a table using RSelenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm scraping the 'dynamic' table from bottom of this site: http://arbejdsmarkedsbalancen.dk/da/Historik.aspx?group=Akademisk%20arbejde&region=%7CNordjylland%7C&jobOpportunities=|||||||||||||5|3|2|4|1|&chart=Skemaoversigt&years=|2015-1|2015-2|

On the site it looks like this with the first column being the name of different occupation (in danish) and the second and third row being a color-indicator [image]

Hence what I wish to make is a table that looks something like this:

```
1. column                          2. column  3. column
Adjunkt, Humaniora                 yellow     yellow
Adjunkt, Naturvidenskab Og Teknik  yellow     yellow
....                               ....       ....
```

and so on.

As i can't find the table structure in the html-source code I assumed it was generated with some other script and had to be extracted using RSelenium.

My code so far looks like this

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)

server <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- server$client

url <- "http://arbejdsmarkedsbalancen.dk/da/Historik.aspx?group=Akademisk%20arbejde&region=%7CNordjylland%7C&jobOpportunities=|||||||||||||5|3|2|4|1|&chart=Skemaoversigt&years=|2015-1|2015-2|"
remDr$navigate(url)

list <- readHTMLTable(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]], encoding="UTF-8")
final.table <- list[[1]]

View(final.table)
```

This leaves me with this output.

[image: output]

Do anyone know whether I can extract the color from the color or any other indicator of the color in the second and third column?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The bedst way to go about it was to use rvest instead of the XML-packages, the solution goes as follows:

```
page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table.1 <- page %>%  html_nodes("table") %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
table.1 <- table.1[[1]]
table.1 <- table.1[-nrow(table.1),]
colnames(table.1) <- c("Stilling","firsthalf","secondhalf")

table.2 <- page %>%  html_nodes("td") %>% html_attr("style") %>% gsub("background-color:", "", .)
table.2.a <- table.2[seq(1,length(table.2),3)]
table.2.b <- table.2[seq(2,length(table.2),3)]
table.2.b <- table.2.b[-length(table.2.b)] 
table.2.c <- table.2[seq(3,length(table.2),3)]
table.2.c <- table.2.c[-length(table.2.c)]

table.1$firsthalf <- table.2.b
table.1$secondhalf <- table.2.c
```